# pop3 caching proxy

Tags: proxy, cache, pop3, slow-connection

I have a really slow and unreliable internet connection at the office.
I also have one email account where many people download mail from the same account without deleting them form the server. (kind of a shared bugs/support/alarms account that everyone checks).

Sometimes a client would send a large trace that everyone would download separately hogging the bandwidth for very long.

I was thinking of installing a pop3 caching proxy server for this particular account, that everyone would connect to and will download the email from the server the first time someone requests it then serve the same email from the cache to all the other users when the check their mail.

Or maybe periodically check the the real server every minute and download emails, regardless of internal clients connecting to it, then always server the clients form the cache.

I have a spare ubuntu server I can use for this, is there something ready that can do this?

Should I manually install a pop3 server and a pop3 client (recommendations?) and configure the client to download the mails and save them in the same format and same folder the server expects to find the mailbox in?

Any other ideas that can help in such situations?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) to download the mail to a server every few minutes then use [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) to serve it up as POP3 or IMAP

Both are relatively easy to configure.

Answer (score 2):

You could use fetchmail to get the mails from the remote server. All users can then use the ubuntu server as their mail server and pull the mails locally.

The needed effort on the server side is relatively low, but you need to configure the local pop3 server on all clients.

Answer (score 0):

FreePOPS — http://www.freepops.org/en/