# Serve IMAP Account as POP

Tags: email, imap, gmail, pop3

I have ran into this a few times:

I get a new email address that can only be accessed by IMAP or through a web browser. I want to read mail from all of my other accounts through my gmail account.

Gmail lets me connect to other pop servers out in the world, but not IMAP.

Well, to get around this in the past I have created a forwarding rule in for my new email address and have all the email sent to an account that I can access by POP and get the email to gmail that way.

Well now I have a new university email account that I can't access by POP but only IMAP and Outlook Web Access. In OWA, I don't have the option to set up the forwarding rule.

What can I do?

I have looked for some software that will download email from an IMAP account and serve it through POP, but I can't find any.

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/5666/pop3-caching-proxy/5670  the same will work here

Answer (score 3):

There is a free tool (GPL), written in Java: [IMAP4 to POP3 protocol gateway](http://www.kohsuke.org/imap2pop/).

> This tool allows you to access IMAP4
>   server as if it were a POP3 server.
>   It's useful when your IMAP4 server
>   doesn't support POP3 for some reason.

This gateway reads mail from the specified IMAP4 server like a proxy:

```
               IMAP4                POP3              
IMAP Server ----------> Gateway -----------> you/Gmail
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's disappointingly untechnical, but have you tried asking your University sysadmins to set up email forwarding?

I used to be one and we were all pretty friendly types!

Comment: I have and I am waiting on the response. But I would still like to know how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set up an outlook filter that includes a forward directly to GMail, assuming the admins haven't disabled the filtering.